# New/Established user property definition in firebase?

Tags: firebase-analytics

I want to know definition of New/Established user property in firebase. We can filter using these user property. I searched for it's definition in firebase but found nothing.

Here is the firebase link of user properties.

[Firebase User properties](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6317519?hl=en)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

New = first_open occurred within the last 7 days

Established = Not New

Comment: Could you please provide the source?

Comment: In documentation - https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6317486?hl=en